# remove trailing zeros from column based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a following data frame:

```
set.seed(12)
id<-rep(letters[1:10],each=20)
var1<-rbinom(200,1,0.25)   
df<-data.frame(id, var1)
```

I would like to remove zeros at the end of var1 for each id if the number of repeating zeros
is larger than or equal to the number of subsequently repeating zeros anywhere within the data frame for a particular id.

example:

```
df[df$id=="a",]

 id var1
1   a    0
2   a    1
3   a    1
4   a    0
5   a    0
6   a    0
7   a    0
8   a    0
9   a    0
10  a    0
11  a    0
12  a    1
13  a    0
14  a    0
15  a    0
16  a    0
17  a    0
18  a    0
19  a    0
20  a    0
```

For id "a", we have a series of 8 subsequent zeros at the end, which is the same length as a previous series of zeros, therefore, zeros at the end should be removed and new id "a" should look like this:

```
 id var1
1   a    0
2   a    1
3   a    1
4   a    0
5   a    0
6   a    0
7   a    0
8   a    0
9   a    0
10  a    0
11  a    0
12  a    1
```

For id "b", we see there are only 2 subsequent zeros at the end, which is less than max number of subsequent zeros and therefore nothing should be done.

```
df[df$id=="b",]


 id var1
21  b    0
22  b    1
23  b    0
24  b    0
25  b    0
26  b    0
27  b    0
28  b    0
29  b    0
30  b    0
31  b    0
32  b    1
33  b    1
34  b    1
35  b    0
36  b    1
37  b    0
38  b    1
39  b    0
40  b    0
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
set.seed(12)
id<-rep(letters[1:10],each=20)
var1<-rbinom(200,1,0.25)   
df<-data.frame(id, var1)

library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

setDT(df)

to_remove <- 
  # get all run lengths of 0s
  df[, .N, .(id, var1, rleid(var1))][var1 == 0] %>% 
    # only for ids with trailing 0s
    .[df[, if (last(var1) == 0) id, id], on = .(id)] %>% 
    # only if the last is longer than all previous for that id
    .[, if (last(N) >= max(N[-.N])) .(n_rem = last(N)), id] %>% 
    .[, setNames(n_rem, id)]

to_remove
#> a h 
#> 8 8

df[,  head(.SD, .N - fcoalesce(to_remove[id], 0L))
   , by = id] 
#>      id var1
#>   1:  a    0
#>   2:  a    1
#>   3:  a    1
#>   4:  a    0
#>   5:  a    0
#>  ---        
#> 180:  j    0
#> 181:  j    0
#> 182:  j    1
#> 183:  j    0
#> 184:  j    0
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

In a single chain:

```
df[, .N, .(id, var1, rleid(var1))][var1 == 0] %>% 
  .[df[, if (last(var1) == 0) id, id], on = .(id)] %>% 
  .[, if (last(N) >= max(N[-.N])) .(n_rem = last(N)), id] %>% 
  .[, setNames(n_rem, id)] %>% 
  {df[, head(.SD, .N - fcoalesce(.[id], 0L)), id]}

#      id var1
#   1:  a    0
#   2:  a    1
#   3:  a    1
#   4:  a    0
#   5:  a    0
#  ---        
# 180:  j    0
# 181:  j    0
# 182:  j    1
# 183:  j    0
# 184:  j    0
```

Answer (score 0):

We create a function with `rle` - with two parameters 'x' and the threshold ('thresh'), apply the `rle` (run-length-encoding) on the input 'x' (`rle` - returns a `list` output with `lengths` and `values` as two vectors).  Check whether the last element of `values` is 0 and its corresponding `lengths` is greater than or equal to the threshold passed, then replace the last element of logical TRUE vector ('tmp1') to FALSE, and return the `rep`licated 'tmp1'.

Do a group by 'id' in `ave`, apply the function and `subset` the rows

```
f1 <-  function(x, thresh) {
     with(rle(x), {
         tmp1 <- rep(TRUE, length(values))
        tmp2 <- values[length(values)]
         tmp1[length(tmp1)][tmp2 == 0 & lengths[length(values)] >= thresh] <- FALSE
     rep(tmp1, lengths)
 })
}
```

-testing

```
out <- subset(df, as.logical(ave(var1, id, FUN = function(x) f1(x, 8))))
```

-output

```
> subset(out, id == 'a')
   id var1
1   a    0
2   a    1
3   a    1
4   a    0
5   a    0
6   a    0
7   a    0
8   a    0
9   a    0
10  a    0
11  a    0
12  a    1
> subset(out, id == 'b')
   id var1
21  b    0
22  b    1
23  b    0
24  b    0
25  b    0
26  b    0
27  b    0
28  b    0
29  b    0
30  b    0
31  b    0
32  b    1
33  b    1
34  b    1
35  b    0
36  b    1
37  b    0
38  b    1
39  b    0
40  b    0
```

Comment: I like this solution, however, threshold is set manually. Is there a way to set it for each id automatically?

Comment: @FranKostanjsek Just change the thresh to `max(lengths[values ==0])`

Answer (score 0):

Version that is a single pipeline for no particular reason:

```
set.seed(12)
id<-rep(letters[1:10],each=20)
var1<-rbinom(200,1,0.25)   
df<-data.frame(id, var1)

df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    tidyr::nest() %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        data = purrr::map(data, ~rle(.x$var1)),
        max = purrr::map_int(data, ~max(.x$lengths[.x$values == 0])),
        last = purrr::map_int(data, ~{
            .x$lengths[.x$values == 0][length(.x$lengths[.x$values == 0])]
        })
    ) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
        data = purrr::map(
            data, ~{
                if(max > last) {
                    x <- inverse.rle(.x)
                    len <- length(x)
                    x[(len - last):len] <- NA
                    x
                } else {
                    inverse.rle(.x)
                }
            }
        )
    ) %>%
    dplyr::select(id, data) %>%
    tidyr::unnest(c(id, data)) %>%
    tidyr::drop_na()
```

Comment: Sorry for late response, is there a way to include other variables? For example, if our data frame had additional column var2<-rnorm(200,1,1) ? Because when I use it on my data, it does exactly what I asked for, however, other variables get filtered out, which is something I didn't consider when asking the question.

Comment: Yes. The `dplyr::select(id, data)` line keeps only those two columns and the `group_by(id)` & `tidyr::nest()` lines determine which columns end up nested into the data column which I used in to apply the logic by group. If you keep any extra columns out of the nested column then select them at the end you should be fine. Stepping through the pipeline by commenting out each pipe `%>%` and everything after it should make it a little clearer whats happening at each step so you can adapt it, also helpful is assigning the intermediates to an object `x` and looking at the data column `x$data[[1]]`

Comment: Actually if you want to apply the same rule to multiple columns and not just have additional columns with data you don't need processed in the same way you would likely need `dplyr::across`, and you may run into issues with the `drop_na` at the end for results of a different length. I suspect it would be easier to use `tidyr::pivot_longer` and group_by both varX and id